# Win7 systray style popup

Tags: vb.net, notifications, systray, tray

Hello guys
I have an applcation that sets itself to 0 opacity on Form1_load which then changes to 1 when the user left clicks on the NotifyIcon. I would also like the form to center itself directy above the notifyicon like the Win7 speakers, power, ect popups.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of setting the opacity to 0, call `Hide()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned; I wouldn't bother with .Opacity unless you are using values beyond 0 and 1.  I believe it will be more clear (and more performant, but I'm speculating) to use .Show and .Hide.

To center a form above the NotifyIcon in the System Try; you might want to just grabbing the mouse position and the screen size.  Inside the NotifyIcon_Click event you could do...

```
Dim xPos As Integer = MousePosition.X
```

And center your form over that position.  It won't technically be perfectly centered over the NotifyIcon - if you click on the left edge, it would be centered over the left edge.  You can use .GetWorkingArea on the PrimaryScreen to get the height and position the Y value appropriately.

Comment: I have tried using .hide and .show but `Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load Me.Hide() 'Opacity = 0 End Sub` doesn't want to work for me

Comment: That's because `Load` is fired before the form is shown.  Handle `Shown` instead.

Comment: Ahh okay, Dim xPos As Integer = MousePosition.X also worked great, thank you.